# How can I programatically register a feature class as versioned

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

Is there a way to programatically register a feature class as versioned?

I'm able to register a`FeatureDataset`with the [IVersionObject3 interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/RegisterAsVersioned3_Method/002500000m1q000000/), but not an individual feature class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeodatabase/Register_As_Versioned_Example.htm) example:

```
public void RegisterDataset(IDataset dataset)
{ 
    IVersionedObject3 versionedObject = (IVersionedObject3)dataset;

    bool IsRegistered;
    bool IsMovingEditsToBase;

    versionedObject.GetVersionRegistrationInfo(out IsRegistered, out IsMovingEditsToBase);

    if(IsRegistered)
    {
        if(IsMovingEditsToBase)
        {
            //first unregister without compressing edits
            versionedObject.UnRegisterAsVersioned3(false);

            //then register as fully versioned
            versionedObject.RegisterAsVersioned3(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //registering as fully versioned
        versionedObject.RegisterAsVersioned3(false);
    }
}
```

IVersionedObject3 is implemented by IDataset. IDataset implements IFeatureClass and IFeatureDataset so it should work for either.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m18000000), IVersionedObject3 is implemented by NetworkDataset, CadastralFabric, StreetNetwork and Utility network... So, In theory, there is no way I can cast a FeatureClass insite a IVersionedObject3. In the same way, looking at the FeatureClass coclass documentation(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000000mq000000), there is no sign of IVersionEdit implementation.

Comment: Even if it's not documented, I tested you solution and it works! Esri should update it's documentation though.

Comment: Yes I think so. The listed interfaces do not include IDataset and as it implements that I think that's important. I think Esri has a "suggestions box"; it would be worth logging this as a deficiency.